# Representation Functions

Tags: combinatorics

I came across the following problem about representation functions:

> Produce a set $A$ such that $r(n) > 0$ for all $n \in [1,N]$, but with $|A| \leq \sqrt{4N+1}$.

Note that $$r(n) = \left|\{(a, a'): a, a' \in A, n = a+a' \} \right|$$

I think $A = \{0,1,2 \}$ would work with the interval being $[1,4]$. Then $3 \leq \sqrt{17}$.

A second part of the question shows that one can prove that $|A| \leq \sqrt{N}$  if it satisfies the above conditions. But $3 > \sqrt{4} = 2$. Does this mean that my set $A$ is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a misprint in (the first edition of) [Analytic Number Theory](ftp://195.214.211.1/books/DVD-004/Newman_D.J._Analytic_number_theory_%281998%29%28en%29%2878s%29.pdf) by Donald Newman (p. 15). Several Amazon reviews ([here](http://tinyurl.com/german-newman) and [here](http://tinyurl.com/dotcom-newman)) state that that printing is full of errors (and that some have also remained in the second edition).

It should be $|A|\ge\sqrt{N}$, since you need at least that many numbers in $A$ to form enough pairs to produce all the $N$ numbers.

Comment: This particular +1 goes to [Google](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22Produce+a+set+A+such+that+r%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) ;-)

Comment: @joriki: Thanks. I guess this isn't a good book to learn analytic number theory from?

Comment: I'm not competent to make a recommendation on that. I do love the crazy dice example, though :-)

Comment: @Damien: Don't let the typos deter you from reading that book! It is not intended to be a text book for analytic number theory, but I found it pretty interesting nonetheless and IMO, a good motivator to further learn the subject.